# With Google Drive API, how do I find a filename that contains a string of digits?

Tags: google-drive-api

With the Drive API I can find matching filenames by calling [`Files: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) with query `q` set to `name contains 'SO8393'`. I get back matching files like this:

```json
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "111111",
   "name": "-SO8393_8041HE.pdf",
  },
  {
   "id": "222222",
   "name": "-SO8393_8041VENDORX.pdf",
  }
 ]
}
```

However, if I modify my query `q` to have only digits and no alpha characters, like `name contains '8393'`, then I get back *no* matching files:

```json
{
 "files": []
}
```

I also tried double quotes, i.e., `name contains "8393"`, but got the same empty list in return. This is very surprising to not match on strings that are just digits.

How *do* you match filenames when your `name contains` argument is only digits?

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

*Use `fullText` instead of `name`: `fullText contains '8393'`*

### Explanation

- `name` returns files whose name has exactly the same word as the searched word
- `fullText` returns files whose name contains the searched word even if it is included in another word

### Reference

[Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Answer (score 1):

With further investigation, this is not an issue specific to digits in the name, as my original question asked about. Instead, it has to do with how the file's `name` is tokenized/indexed and can be matched, if at all. These footnotes on the `contains` operator explain some of the behavior I'm seeing: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fn1 and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fn2

@fullfine your suggestion to use `fullText` is a good one and gets us closer, but does not cover the general case for any substring in the file's `name`, like `z123`. The table below shows some examples.

Here is the experiment setup, with these four files in a Shared Drive. Each of these files are identical in content -- a blank PDF file. So this leaves only the `name` of the file to match on, as the body of the PDF contains nothing.

[image: four files in a google drive folder]

Here are several variations on queries using `name contains` and `fullText contains`, and the resulting files that match. (Tell me if I've missed some queries to try, and I'll run them and add them to the table.)

| Query `q` using `name` | Files matched and returned |
| --- | --- |
| `name contains '123'` | `Abc-123-test.pdf` `Xyz-123-test.pdf` |
| `name contains "123"` | `Abc-123-test.pdf` `Xyz-123-test.pdf` |
| `name contains 'z123'` |  |
| `name contains "z123"` |  |
| `name contains 'xyz123'` | `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `name contains "xyz123"` | `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `name contains 'xyz test'` |  |
| `name contains "xyz test"` |  |
| `name contains 'z 123'` |  |
| `name contains "z 123"` |  |
| `name contains 'xyz 123'` |  |
| `name contains "xyz 123"` |  |

| Query `q` using `fullText` | Files matched and returned |
| --- | --- |
| `fullText contains '123'` | `Abc-123-test.pdf` `Abc123test.pdf` `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `fullText contains "123"` | `Abc-123-test.pdf` `Abc123test.pdf` `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `fullText contains 'z123'` |  |
| `fullText contains "z123"` |  |
| `fullText contains 'xyz123'` |  |
| `fullText contains "xyz123"` |  |
| `fullText contains 'xyz test'` | `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `fullText contains "xyz test"` | `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `fullText contains 'z 123'` |  |
| `fullText contains "z 123"` |  |
| `fullText contains 'xyz 123'` | `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |
| `fullText contains "xyz 123"` | `Xyz-123-test.pdf` `Xyz123test.pdf` |

Matching "xyz test" seems inconsistent with the documentation [footnote 3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fn2):

> For example, if the fullText of a doc contains the string "Hello there world", then the query fullText contains '"Hello there"' will return a result, but the query fullText contains '"Hello world"' will not.

...unless it it tokenizes `123` and drops it as if it were not alphanumeric.

Also, in [footnote [2]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fn2):

> The contains operator only performs matching on entire string tokens for fullText.

Given the experiment, it looks like it breaks up tokens on `[a-zA-Z]` and `[0-9]` separately, given that a query for `z123` does not match, since that would span separate tokens and not match tokens in their entirety.

**It appears to be impossible to query for a file name that matches substring `z123`.**

Comment: The file search behavior in Google Drive works as you say and does not support filtering by substrings in a token. If you want this to change you can open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) for Google to study its implementation.